# angular custom input for complex object

Tags: angular, angular-forms

i have  a object with 3 string members and I want to make a reusable input for it because it is used many times all over the application, so I'm trying to create a Custom Input that contains all 3 member's inputs. But i didn't found out a way, because other solutions that I've found don't let me to pass a complex object (MyObject) trough `ngModel` to my Custom Input component.
To add complexity to my Question I need also to validate my Custom Input:
if my custom input is `required` all of 3 sub-inputs are `required`.
if one of sub-inputs gets filled the other 2 are `required`,
if one of sub-inputs is invalid my Custom Input is invalid too.

Here an example of how I'd want my code to work (If possible)

**MyObject.ts**

```
export class MyObject {
    name: string;
    category: string;
    areaName: string;
}
```

**MyFormComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-form'
    template: `
     <form #myForm="ngForm">
       <my-object-input [(ngModel)]="myObj" ></my-object-input>
     </form>`
})
export class MyFormComponent {
    myObj: MyObject;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to implement ControlValueAccessor to create a custum input that takes in ngModel or formControl. Refer this blog https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues to solve your task by creating Custom Form Control. Follow this well-explained article [custom-form-controls-in-angular-2](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html).
In this article you also can find the way of adding custom validation rules.

The general idea is to implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface in your custom form control and add your logic inside the custom `writeValue(value: any)` method.